# How to handle spring jpa @transactional and new inserts from catch block

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, transactions

I got this code. I am using spring boot and jpa

```
@Transactional

public class MyClass {

    public void createSomething() {
        try {
            saveAndFlush();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Since error has occured I want to insert this information
            // into a audit table

            repository.saveAndFlush();

        }
    }

}
```

Now when the exception happens, the transaction is rolled back and hence the error table insert is not happening.

I am seeing

> HHH000099: an assertion failure occured (this may indicate a bug in Hibernate, but is more likely due to unsafe use of the session): org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in XXXXX entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)

In order to fix this I tried to do the error insert in a new method marked with `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)` on the understanding that the inner transaction would complete and outer would roll back

But I don't see my intended output.

Comment: Correct. It is indeed a duplicate

Comment: @alan-hay - even after following the instructions in your original thread i am still seeing the same issue. I made it as transactional in individual methods and added a requires new propogation

Comment: `REQUIRES_NEW` will only work if that method is called on another object. If you marked a method inside this class with `REQUIRES_NEW` and call it from within this class it won't work. This is due to the limitations of proxy based AOP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `@Transactional` from class level, and use it on those methods which actually perform the transactions. (if you have more than 1 method in that class, of course).

If you want independent transactions to commit/rollback to database, then use REQUIRES_NEW propagation on the method which will not disturb the global transaction.

The default behavior of '@Transactional' without any propagation mentioned is, to join the global (calling) transaction if any available, and if not start a new transaction.

Since you have a global transaction, it is rolledback completely. Instead, you need independent transactions.

Comment: I made it as individual transactions and still don't see it working.